# User role change with project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I need following association in my app.

```
User has many role,
Project has many user,
```

user1: manager for project 1 & employee for project 2

I am not getting idea about how can I set relationship between these tables and models.

**User**, **Role** and **Project**

How can I set this up?

Thanks a lot in advice.

Comment: `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins`

Comment: i am not getting it, Can you give me example?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use some gems.

1. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
2. [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)

Then create the `project` model + controller + views.

create a new user - `User.create(email: "user1@example.com", password: "123123")`

add role to the newly created user - `User.last.add_role(:manager)`

create another user - `User.create(email: "user2@example.com", password: "123123")`

add role to the newly created user - `User.last.add_role(:employee)`

Now, if you do all the steps right, then create a new Project:

```
user1_project = User.find(1).projects.new(project_params)
```

It will create a project for user with email **user1@eaxmple.com** who has **manager** role.

Comment: i am already done with singal role to user and parmissions, now i want to give user multipal role, Like user is manager for 1 project and employe for other project

Comment: If you want to add multiple role to user try: `User.find(1).add_role(:employee)` Thus, user1 has 2 roles

Comment: How can i track that user's employee for project 1 and admin for project 2 in ability class

Comment: Have you checked the gems? If you read the docs you can easily figure out how to find what you're looking for. `Project.find(1).user.roles` will give you Project1 user roles.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this,

Create a table call role and give unique id to each role_type, like

1 for manager, 2 for employee, 3 for owner etc.
And create another table which have the following fields,

user_id,role_id,project_id

So if user1 is manager of project1 then we will have a entry with the following entry

user_id = 1, role_id = 1, project_id = 1

and user1 is employee for project2 will have an entry,

user_id =  1, role_id = 2, project_id = 2

here role_id 1 and 2 corresponds to manager and employee respectively.

Answer (score 0):

if you asking about how to add the relationship to the tables.

Here is an example

Let's say

```
Users -> user1, user2
Roles -> Role1, Role2
Projects -> P1, P2

Users -> Roles ( foreign key relationship ) users depends on Roles
Roles -> Projects ( foreign key relationship ) Roles depends on Projects
```

Here let's treat project as resource where a role can access them

```
Users -> Roles -> Projects
```

Roles can have read permission on P1 and read-write permission on P2 etc

Comment: No All three are sepret But user can asses projects as par role. @chinna2580

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this setting up [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)  gem.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
end


class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
end
```

Now you can add multiple roles to user object either by specifying particular project object or Project class or without these. For example:

```
user = User.create(user_params)

project_1 = Project.create(project_params)
project_1 = Project.create(project_params)

# Add roles with respect to specific project object
user.add_role('manager', project_1)
user.add_role('employee', project_2)
```

Please go through this [rolify documentation](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Usage) to get the detailed overview and usage examples.